# No such file or directory error

Tags: python

This is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\stuff\module.py", line 91, in <module>
    f = open('E:/stuff/log.txt')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'E:/stuff/log.txt'
```

And this is my code:

```
f = open('E:/stuff/log.txt')
```

The `E:/stuff/log.txt` file exists. I can navigate in Windows Explorer and open it so why can't I open it?

EDIT:

Output of DIR command:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>dir e:\stuff
 Volume in drive E has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 5660-4957

 Directory of e:\stuff

23. 10. 2010  09:26    <DIR>          .
23. 10. 2010  09:26    <DIR>          ..
19. 10. 2010  20:07               385 index.py
23. 10. 2010  16:12             1 954 module.py
22. 10. 2010  19:16             8 335 backprop.py
19. 10. 2010  20:54             1 307 backprop-input.gif
19. 10. 2010  01:48               310 HelloWorld.kpf
23. 10. 2010  15:47                 0 log.txt.txt
               6 File(s)         12 291 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   8 795 586 560 bytes free



C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>dir e:\
 Volume in drive E has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 5660-4957

 Directory of e:\

16. 10. 2010  13:32    <DIR>          development-tools
23. 10. 2010  09:26    <DIR>          stuff
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   8 795 586 560 bytes free
```

I am running the python script from the cmd like this:

```
python E:\stuff\module.py
```

Comment: "I can navigate in Windows Explorer".  So?  Do a "DIR" command from the command prompt and copy and paste that, too.

Comment: @S. Lott I did that. See my updated question.

Comment: @Richard: that was not a command prompt, that was python interpreter.

Comment: Are you saying the `dir` command does not show the `e:\stuff` directory?  That's your problem.  There's no `e:\stuff` directory.  Or are you saying you can't do `dir E:`?  What did you post?  Why did you post that?

Comment: Sorry. I just posted output of "dir" from cmd. I added outputs of "dir e:\" and "dir e:\stuff".

Comment: `log.txt.txt` is not the same as `log.txt`, or is it?

Comment: @Richard: and? do you not see the issue yourself?

Comment: Damn it. I see it now. SilentGhost, please write it in an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Richard: it doesn't really worth it. Accept tim's answer or just delete the question. It is of little use for the community.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firstly, from above, Windows supports / just fine.

Secondly:
Well, if you look at your file, you'll notice it's not log.txt, it's log.txt.txt... You may see it as "log.txt" in your graphical folder viewer (as opposed to the CLI "dir" command) simply because it hides the known file extensions.

I recommend you disable this - see folder options, there should be an option "Hide extensions of known file types" (or similar).

Answer (score 4):

Look at this line in the "dir" output:

```
23. 10. 2010  15:47                 0 log.txt.txt
```

The file you are looking for is named "log.txt.txt", not "log.txt". I see this happen when people set up the Windows file manager to not show known file extensions and then they try to add or modify an extension. I recommend to others that they turn this behavior off. You can do this under View->Folder Options I believe.

Comment: Just one note: People don't "set it up" this way, it is (unfortunately) the default behavior. A horrible, *horrible* idea, in my opinion, but sadly, that's how it is.

Answer (score 1):

how about reading permissions? maybe not authorized to read (default mode of open)

Answer (score 1):

Since it is windows, and the backslash is a escape character, you must double the backslash to escape it. Try

```
e:\\stuff\\log.txt
```

Comment: Why not use r"e:\stuff\log.txt"?  Why not use `os.path.join( "E:", "stuff", "log.txt" )`?

Comment: OP is using forward slashes - escaping is _not_ an issue here. As brady and Tim rightly point out, the `log.txt` file does _not_ exist, it's `log.txt.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

it been a long time that i didn't use windows, but if i remember well windows use back-slash in system path so you should do:

```
import os

file_name = os.path.join("e:\\stuff", "log.txt")

f = open(file_name)
```

and not:

```
f = open('E:/stuff/log.txt')
```

there is not / in paths in windows.

Comment: Python does actually handle forward slashes okay - it may not have when you used it, I don't know how long ago that was :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: excuse me ? i didn't understand, i said that windows don't use backslash in path like unix. when did i said that python doesn't handle forward slash ?

Comment: You said not to use `f = open('E:/stuff/log.txt')` when in fact that will work fine. You don't need backslashes.

Comment: @paxdiablo:correct me if i'm wrong, but i think that windows don't have path like this __E:/stuff/log.txt__ no forward slash, they use backslash like this :  __E:\stuff\log.txt__ , you see the difference :)

Comment: Yes I see the difference but Windows itself handles this as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx#paths : "Note  File I/O functions in the Windows API convert "/" to "\" as part of converting the name to an NT-style name, except when using the "\\?\" prefix as detailed in the following sections." You can see this in the question. The code used forward slash but the error message used backslash.

Comment: @paxdiablo : ahh ok, thank you very much for the info, like i said it's been a long time that i didn't use windows :), and so windows normalize the path without the need to call : os.path.normpath() , heh !!

Answer (score 1):

Define you path names using `os.path.join()`

```
root="E:\\"
mylog = os.path.join(root,"stuff","log.txt") # or log.txt.txt as seen in your dir output
f = open(mylog)
...
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

just use raw string with absolute path

```
file_path = r"E:\stuff\log.txt"
```

this should work fine

Answer (score 0):

Following Worked for me. Instead of using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`
use `context.getFilesDir()`. 
Following peice of code worked for me.

```
public void create_file(Context context, String sFileName, String sBody) {
        try {
            File root = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "NEC_TEXT");
            if (!root.exists()) {
                root.mkdir();
            }
            File filepath = new File(root, sFileName);
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filepath);
            writer.append(sBody);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();



           }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer appears to be written for a different question. And a different language than python